# Split text beginning at the start of a string

Tags: bash

I have a lot of text that looks like the following:

```
'str_aaa_2012-0000.txt' 'http://weburl.com' 'SHA256' 'hashdata' 'str_aaa_2012-0001.txt' 'http://weburl.com' 'SHA256' 'hashdata' 'str_aaa_2012-0002.txt' 'http://weburl.com' 'SHA256' 'hashdata' 'str_aaa_2012-0003.txt' 'http://weburl.com' 'SHA256' 'hashdata' 'str_aaa_2012-0004.txt' 'http://weburl.com' 'SHA256' 'hashdata' 'str_aaa_2012-0005.txt' 'http://weburl.com' 'SHA256' 'hashdata'
```

The first string containing `str_aaa` varies at the end, the second string containing the URL varies, the third string containing `SHA256` stays the same through the text, and the fourth string containing `hashdata` varies. I want to split each line starting at the string `'str_aaa_2012*`, so that the output will look like:

```
'str_aaa_2012-0000.txt' 'http://weburl.com' 'SHA256' 'hashdata'
'str_aaa_2012-0001.txt' 'http://weburl.com' 'SHA256' 'hashdata'
'str_aaa_2012-0002.txt' 'http://weburl.com' 'SHA256' 'hashdata'
'str_aaa_2012-0003.txt' 'http://weburl.com' 'SHA256' 'hashdata'
'str_aaa_2012-0004.txt' 'http://weburl.com' 'SHA256' 'hashdata'
```

How might I go about splitting this text into individual lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -aF\' -ne '
    shift @F,
        print join "\x27", "", splice(@F, 0, 7), "\n"
        while @F > 1;
' input-file
```

`-aF\'` splits the line into the @F array on `'`. Elements are then removed from the array in groups and printed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this gnu-sed command:

```
sed -E "s/(('[^']*' ){3}'[^']*') +/\1\n/g" file
'str_aaa_2012-0000.txt' 'http://weburl.com' 'SHA256' 'hashdata'
'str_aaa_2012-0001.txt' 'http://weburl.com' 'SHA256' 'hashdata'
'str_aaa_2012-0002.txt' 'http://weburl.com' 'SHA256' 'hashdata'
'str_aaa_2012-0003.txt' 'http://weburl.com' 'SHA256' 'hashdata'
'str_aaa_2012-0004.txt' 'http://weburl.com' 'SHA256' 'hashdata'
'str_aaa_2012-0005.txt' 'http://weburl.com' 'SHA256' 'hashdata'
```

Answer (score 1):

With Bash parameter expansion:

```
$ str="'str_aaa_2012-0000.txt' 'http://weburl.com' 'SHA256' 'hashdata' 'str_aaa_2012-0001.txt' 'http://weburl.com' 'SHA256' 'hashdata' 'str_aaa_2012-0002.txt' 'http://weburl.com' 'SHA256' 'hashdata' 'str_aaa_2012-0003.txt' 'http://weburl.com' 'SHA256' 'hashdata' 'str_aaa_2012-0004.txt' 'http://weburl.com' 'SHA256' 'hashdata' 'str_aaa_2012-0005.txt' 'http://weburl.com' 'SHA256' 'hashdata'"
$ printf "%b\n" "${str// \'str_aaa/\\n\'str_aaa}"
'str_aaa_2012-0000.txt' 'http://weburl.com' 'SHA256' 'hashdata'
'str_aaa_2012-0001.txt' 'http://weburl.com' 'SHA256' 'hashdata'
'str_aaa_2012-0002.txt' 'http://weburl.com' 'SHA256' 'hashdata'
'str_aaa_2012-0003.txt' 'http://weburl.com' 'SHA256' 'hashdata'
'str_aaa_2012-0004.txt' 'http://weburl.com' 'SHA256' 'hashdata'
'str_aaa_2012-0005.txt' 'http://weburl.com' 'SHA256' 'hashdata'
```

The finer points of the expansion,

```
printf "%b\n" "${str// \'str_aaa/\\n\'str_aaa}"
```

are:

- [`${str//old/new}`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) replaces `old` with `new` in the parameter `str`, for all occurrences of `old` (as opposed to `${str/old/new}`, which replaces only the first occurrence)
- The single quotes have to be escaped, hence `\'`
- The backslash in the newline character `\n` has to be escaped as well, hence `\\n`
- Instead of just inserting a newline in front of `'str_aaa'`, we replace the space before it to avoid a) an empty line at the start and b) extra spaces at the end of the lines
- To print, we use [`printf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-printf) with its `%b` format specification, which expands backslash escape sequences